# Returning only the portion of a line after a matching pattern (Unix)

Tags: sed, grep

I have a parent folder (abeps) which contains several sub folders (1,2,3....25) where output file is located, one in which - all are the same name  (opt.out). In this files there is an unpredictable output. This is an example of a line that I need to filter:

> A\HF=-1378.9118397\RMSD=4.560e-09\RMSF=1.758e-05\Dipole=0.2110167,0.39

or

> 978,3.8529967641,3.6669041122\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-A\HF=-

so the thing is I'm interested in getting everything in between \HF= and till \

But they could be on different lines, and even HF could be on different lines, so grep won't catch it. Then I tried to write result in a file:

```
grep 'HF=-' abeps/*/opt.out > data
```

and as result get this

> abeps/10/opt.out: 1-A\HF=-1378.9114895\RMSD=5.126e-09\RMSF=5.036
>
> abeps/12/opt.out: \State=1-A\HF=-1378.9185518\RMSD=2.940e-09\RMSF
>
> abeps/13/opt.out: 33413\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-A\HF=-137

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "even HF could be on different lines"? are you saying there may be a newline between the H and the F?

Comment: Yes some times. It could be "\HF" on one line or "\H" on one line or even only "\" and "HF" on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of grep supports PCRE (Perl Compatible regular Expressions) you could use Perl's lookbehind and lookahead capabilities

```
grep -oPz '(?<=\\HF=)(.|\n)+?(?=\\)'
```

or with `pcregrep` (if available)

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?<=\\HF=)(.|\n)+?(?=\\)'
```

Bear in mind that if your pattern of interest really is split over lines, then the returned text will retain the newline - you may wish to strip it out with `tr` or `sed` before using the result.

If the text itself can't be split over lines (only the `\HF` and `\` markers) then you can replace `(.|\n)+?` by the simpler `.+?` i.e.

```
grep -oPz '(?<=\\HF=).+?(?=\\)'
```

If even the `\HF=` marker may be split at any point by a newline (as indicated by your comment to the original post), then a slightly different approach is required since PCRE does not currently support variable-length lookbehinds. In that case, you can try

```
grep -oPz '\\\n?H\n?F\n?=\K(.|\n)+?(?=\\)'
```

where the lookbehind is replaced by a pseudo-anchor expression using `\K`

Comment: grep -oPz '(?<=\\HF=)(.|\n)+?(?=\\)' Works very well. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Add `(?s)` to have `.` match `\n` as well in PCREs. See also `\K` in newer PCRE versions: `grep -oPz '(?s)\\HF=\K.+?(?=\\)'`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sed`,

```
sed -r '/.*HF=([^\]*)\\?.*/s//\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'A\HF=-1378.9118397\RMSD=4.560e-09\RMSF=1.758e-05\Dipole=0.2110167,0.39' | sed -r '/.*HF=([^\]*)\\?.*/s//\1/g'
-1378.9118397

$ echo '978,3.8529967641,3.6669041122\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-A\HF=-' | sed -r '/.*HF=([^\]*)\\?.*/s//\1/g'
-
```

Answer (score 1):

With recent `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mo1 '(?s)\\HF=(.*?)\\'
```